# Why am I getting this error when I want the the employee to NOT be below 18 and above 60?

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

- the previous error was fixed. A group member was inserting the Salary amount into 0 precision-specified numbers.
- Basically, I want to give an error when the age of an employee is less than 18 or more than 60
- please suggest how I can do it.

**Trigger statement**

```sql
create or replace TRIGGER check_birth_date
      BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON employee
      FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
      IF( months_between(sysdate,:new.DateOfBirth)/12 < 18 or 
          months_between(sysdate,:new.DateOfBirth)/12 > 60 )
      THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( 
          -20001, 
          'EMPLOYEE MUST BE ABOVE 18 AND BELOW 60' );
      END IF;
    END;
```

**The insert statement I am  trying to insert**

```sql
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES(1002, 'DAVID', '21/apr/2011', 'M', '21/jun/2010', 28000.00, 'HR', 'HR MANAGER', 77845322, 'C');
```

**The errors**

```
   - ORA-06512
   - ORA-04088 
   - ORA-20001
```

- [image: 1]

**CREATE TABLE STATEMENT**

```sql
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE(
  EmployeeID NUMBER(4),
  Name VARCHAR2(20),
  Hiredate DATE NOT NULL,
  Gender VARCHAR(1),
  DateOfBirth DATE NOT NULL,
  Salary NUMBER(8,2),
  DName VARCHAR(20),
  PName VARCHAR(20),
  Phone NUMBER(8) NOT NULL,
  GLETTER VARCHAR(1),
  CONSTRAINT EMPLOYEE_EMPLOYEEID_PK PRIMARY KEY(EMPLOYEEID),
  CONSTRAINT EMPLOYEE_DNAME_FK FOREIGN KEY(DNAME) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(DNAME),
  CONSTRAINT EMPLOYEE_PNAME_FK FOREIGN KEY(PNAME) REFERENCES POSITION(PNAME),
  CONSTRAINT EMPLOYEE_GLETTER_FK FOREIGN KEY(GLETTER) REFERENCES GRADE(GLETTER),
  CONSTRAINT GENDER_CK CHECK (GENDER='M' or GENDER='F')
);
```

Comment: I don't think this error has anything to do with the trigger.  You can remove the trigger and see if the error still occurs.

Comment: You probably try to insert a decimal value in an int column.

Comment: Maybe there is a type issue and the actual problem is not with the trigger, the declaration of employee table and the exact line you would like to insert would help a lot.

Comment: Please [edit] the question with a [MRE] including the DDL (`CREATE TABLE`) statement for your table and an example of the DML (`INSERT`) statement for your sample data that is triggering the error.

Comment: edited, let me know if you need anything else. 
Thanks.

Comment: Your trigger is working fine; look at the error message `ORA-20001` is what you told it to raise.

Comment: Why shouldn't employees be over 60 anyway?

Comment: Just as an aside, PHONE should _not_ be a number.  It is not a number, it is a character string that, _by most modern conventions_ uses only numeric characters.  If you were to have a telephone number with leading zeros, they are lost when you store it as NUMBER. You think having the alphabet on a telephone dial/keypad was put there for text messages? Think again.  Declare a column as NUMBER _only_ if it is conceivable to use it in math operations.  Does it make sense to compute the sum of two phone numbers?

Comment: good point @EdStevens, will do so 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is right, if you check your input data and run it by yourself you can see it. I run it and the result is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You trigger is working fine. I have created employee table without any foreign key constraints (since no reference table is available to me) and the trigger is working as it should be.

It's denying entry of any record with age than 18 and more than 60 but it's allowing any record within age 18 to 60.

Please try to insert below line:

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES(1002, 'DAVID', '21/apr/2000', 'M', '21/jun/2000', 28000.00, 'HR', 'HR MANAGER', 77845322, 'C');
```